# I have this code for gosu but it doesn't compile me for the .6 version of gosu, any ideas please

Tags: guidewire, gosu

uses ta.QueryUtil

var output: String = ""

var personIDs = new String[] {"98", "5"}

output += "*****    Count the bank accounts per contact \n"

for (personID in personIDs)

{
  var person = QueryUtil.findPerson(personID)

if (person != null) {

```
output += person.DisplayName + " has " + person.BankAccounts.length + " bank accounts. \n"
```

} else {

```
output += "person not found for " + personID + "\n"
```

}

}

Comment: you should mention the error

Comment: it's successfully runs got an output also,  ***** Count the bank accounts per contact 
Tomohiro Sakurai has 0 bank accounts. 
William Andy has 0 bank accounts.

Comment: Can you upload the screen shot of the compilation issue that you get

Comment: I already uploaded it below in the comment below, I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

because I am selling error when placing use ta.QueryUtil,
and also var person = QueryUtil.findPerson (personID), that's why it doesn't compile me, this pulls well in version 8 however in version 6 I don't know what I have to do

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTLhq.png)